# What's the difference between "object.property" and "document.getElementById().property"

Tags: javascript, dom

I have this HTML:

```
<input id="foo">Hello world!</input>
```

I wonder what the difference between

```
document.getElementById('foo').value
```

and

```
foo.value
```

is in the Javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`foo.value` takes advantage of the global variable `foo` that is created when an element has an `id` established for it. Both versions access the same object and work with the same data.

Accessing an element with just the `id` has been around since the beginnings of JavaScript and remains today, but over time the Document Object Model API was created to have a more robust and complete way of interacting with documents.

Having said this, `document.getElementById()` is the more modern approach. It's part of the **[Document Object Model API standard](https://www.w3.org/DOM/)** and is generally recommended as it is clearer and provides many ways to interact with elements in a web document.

Here's an example.

```js
console.log(div.innerHTML);
div.innerHTML = "New Content!";
console.log(document.getElementById("div").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="div">This is an element</div>
```

Comment: " global variable foo that is created when an element has an id established for it" Is this reliable? What's the point of `document.getElementById()` if it is?

Comment: @gforce301 It is reliable. `document.getElementById()` is one of many methods and properties that allow access to and interaction with a web document. As such, the DOM API (explained in my answer above) is recommended over just using the `id`.